# Conditional Formatting for cells that are higher than 50% is also applied to $ values

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have code I grabbed from a random place.

I have a spreadsheet with over 100 tabs (or sheets).
I want to highlight all cells that are higher than 50%.

I have some $ values in columns A, B and C.
The code also picks up $0.50 - $1.50 and I don't want that.

```vb
Sub AddCF()
    Dim w As Worksheet
    For Each w In Worksheets
        With w.UsedRange.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=0.50", Formula2:="1.50")
            .Font.Color =vbWhite
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
    Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: Check if cell is formatted as currency first?

Answer (score -1):

even though it's probably not the most performatic way to do it, try this:

```
Sub AddCF()
Dim w As Worksheet
For Each w In Worksheets
With w.UsedRange.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=0.50", Formula2:="<1.00")
    .Font.Color = vbWhite
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    
End With

With w.Columns("A:C")
.FormatConditions.Delete
End With
Next w
End Sub
```

Comment: OP wrote `some $ values in column A, B and C.`